# How to Interpret a Shell Variable in a String Value from a CSV Column Using GNU Parallel?

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to use GNU Parallel to execute commands based on the values in a CSV file. My CSV file has multiple columns, and the value in the 5th column of each row is a string that looks like `'${OUTDIR}/test'`.

Here's an example of how my CSV looks:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,'${OUTDIR}/test',col6
```

I want to use GNU Parallel to run mkdir -p on the value of the 5th column, interpreting `${OUTDIR}` as an actual shell variable. For example, if `OUTDIR=/tmp`, then the command should run as `mkdir -p /tmp/test`.

I tried the following command, but it didn't interpret ${OUTDIR}:

```bash
parallel --colsep ',' 'mkdir -p {5}' :::: data.csv
```

produced:

```bash
mkdir -vp \'\$\{OUTDIR\}/test\'
mkdir: created directory ''\''${OUTDIR}'
mkdir: created directory ''\''${OUTDIR}/test'\'''
```

How can I get GNU Parallel to interpret ${OUTDIR} in the string value from the CSV? I've tried using `eval mkdir -p {5}` but that doesn't deal with the quoting as I'd hoped.

Comment: Can you preprocess data.csv, so that you remove the single quotes? Kind of `tr -d "'" data.csv >temp_data.csv; parallel .... :::: temp_data.csv`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `uq()` function as shown by Ole [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/529487/17666):

```
parallel --colsep ',' 'echo {=5 uq(); =}' :::: data.csv
```

Comment: This leads to a follow up that I can't seem to figure out, how do I install a version >20190722 in debian 11. The latest I can seem to get through apt is 20161222. I tried to target the newer versions shown here: https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/parallel but that didn't work.

Comment: @tvandinther See 10 seconds install in https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

Comment: Thank you. The marked answer combined with `eval` is the solution. `parallel --colsep ',' 'eval mkdir -p {=5 uq(); =}' :::: data.csv`